# Django ajax form - redirect to main page after form validation

Tags: django, ajax, forms

I have a `sidenav_form` that is submitted using an ajax post to a view called `form_validation`. The validation errors for **empty fields** or **invalid email** are shown correctly, since when the form is submitted and passed to the view, the view renders the form displaying the errors. Here is the console output:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>Required Field</li></ul></li></ul>
[08/Feb/2020 13:26:37] "POST /patients/validate_form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1253
```

However, the behavior when passing the validator for **repeated email** is different. The error is sent to the request as before, but the user an't see it since it seems that the request redirects to another view...

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This email has already been taken.</li></ul></li></ul>
[08/Feb/2020 13:26:40] "POST /patient/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7769
[08/Feb/2020 13:26:40] "POST /patients/validate_form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1279
```

The `sidenav_form.html` is the following:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!-- sideNav -->
<div class="inside_sidenav">
        <form class="form" id="form_patient">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sidenav-btn-submit" formmethod="post">{% trans 'Guardar'%}
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
    $(function () {
        // SUBMIT DATA
        $('#sidenav-btn-submit').click(function () {
            console.log('noinstance')
            var url = "{% url 'patients:validate_form' %}";
            var formb = $('#form_patient');
            console.log(formb.serialize());
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: formb.serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mySidenav').html(data);
                    openNav();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $('#mySidenav').html(data.responseText);
                    console.log('no ajax2');
                },

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`form_validation` view checks if the form is correct or not. It looks as follows:

```
def validate_form(request, patient_id=None, user_id=None):
    form_initial_data = request.POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(form_initial_data)
        form = UserForm(form_initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form2 is valid')
            # DO SOMETHING
    print(form.errors)
    return render(request, 'patients/sidenav_form.html', {'form1': form})
```

the `form` has the following validator:

```
def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

        if not self.instance.pk:
            try:
                User.objects.get(email=email)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return email
            print('Repeated email')
            raise ValidationError(_("This email has already been taken."))
        return email
```

Do you have any idea why errors related to **empty fields** or **invalid email** renders correctly the form errors but **repeated email** redirects to another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem arises because the button that call the ajax had the property `type` defined as `submit`. Therefore, when the button was pressed it actually made another `post request`, so django started processing two requests at the same time.